# CloudKit Error: Failed to modify some records

Tags: ios, swift, icloud, cloudkit

So I've created this function to upload assets to CloudKit.

```
func uploadAsset(recordType: String, fileURL: URL, reference: String) {
    let record = CKRecord(recordType: recordType)
    record["file"] = CKAsset(fileURL: fileURL)

    let modifyRecordsOperation = CKModifyRecordsOperation(
        recordsToSave: [record],
        recordIDsToDelete: nil)

    modifyRecordsOperation.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 10
    modifyRecordsOperation.timeoutIntervalForResource = 10

    modifyRecordsOperation.modifyRecordsCompletionBlock =
        { records, recordIDs, error in
             print("DEBUG: smodifyRecordsCompletionBlock reached")
            if let err = error {
                print("DEBUG: uhoh error " + err.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                print("DEBUG: success")
            }
    }

    modifyRecordsOperation.perRecordProgressBlock = {
        self.updateProgressView(progress: Float($1))
        print( "DEBUG: progress = ", $1 )
    }

    modifyRecordsOperation.completionBlock = {
        self.hideProgressView(hide: true)
        print("DEBUG: Ding, completion block hit!")
    }

    if (!Reachability.isInternetAvailable()) {
        print("DEBUG: uhoh error no internet connection")
    } else {
        CKContainer(identifier: "iCloud.com.example-container").publicCloudDatabase.add(modifyRecordsOperation)

        print("DEBUG: should have started cloud upload")
    }
}
```

Now this works perfectly fine for myself, but it fails for my client. The error message isn't the most insightful though, it says:

```
DEBUG: should have started cloud upload
file saved
DEBUG: smodifyRecordsCompletionBlock reached
```

I've double checked and my client is signed into iCloud on his test device. What am I missing here?